# Laggy SizeTransition Animation in Flutter Column?

Tags: flutter, animation, dart

I'm trying to animate a panel coming up from the bottom of the screen. My setup is to have a column with two Containers, then animate the size of the lower Container to get a "sliding up" panel effect. The panel shouldn't be on top of the other so I can't use a stack.

Anyway, the problem is using the SizeTransition. I create an AnimationController to control the sizeFactor of the SizeTransition. The problem is that using any Curves in the animation makes it horribly laggy and I don't know why. Obviously, there must be a way to make this run smoothly but I'm at a loss. Here is a minimal example of what I mean:

```
class WelcomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _WelcomePageState createState() => _WelcomePageState();
}

class _WelcomePageState extends State<WelcomePage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
    );
    // Setting to curve: Curves.linear here makes it run smoothly but anything else brings us to choppy town
    _controller.animateTo(210.0, curve: Curves.ease);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(child: Container(color: Colors.blue)),
        SizeTransition(
            sizeFactor: _controller,
            child: Container(
              height: 200,
              color: Colors.green,
            ))
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: you want to animate a `Container` with normal height 200 by passing as a final `sizeFactor` a value 210? inotice that 210 is not a final size: it is a factor, the docs say: *"The animation that controls the (clipped) size of the child.

The width or height (depending on the axis value) of this widget will be its intrinsic width or height multiplied by sizeFactor's value at the current point in the animation."* - so most likely you need `1.05` (200*1.05=210), not `210`

Comment: Okay I feel silly now. That solves it, thank you! My bad :/